# Какая разница между interrupted() и isInterrupted()

Tags: java, многопоточность

Вроде, оба метода проверяют флаг, хотел ли прервать какой-то поток, тот поток, в котором метод был вызван. Поправьте, если я не прав.
Понятно что `isInterrupted()` не статический и его надо вызывать на объекте типа `Thread`, а `interrupted()` статический и можно написать просто `Thread.interrupted()`. Но в чем все таки разница? И в каком потоке флаг будет проверятся, если мы применяем `Thread.interrupted()`, имея в виду что к объекту статические методы не привязаны?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно прочитать javadoc

```
/**
 * Tests whether the current thread has been interrupted.  The
 * <i>interrupted status</i> of the thread is cleared by this method.  In
 * other words, if this method were to be called twice in succession, the
 * second call would return false (unless the current thread were
 * interrupted again, after the first call had cleared its interrupted
 * status and before the second call had examined it)...
 */
public static boolean interrupted()
```

`Thread.interrupted()` вдобавок к проверке снимает флаг прерывания. `thread.isInterrupted()` этого не делает, плюс нестатический доступ позволяет проверять другие треды. Фактически, это еще и ограничивает возможность снять флаг прерывания у других тредов (нельзя "украсть" прерывание другого треда).

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что это для текущего потока который выполнил кнтсрукцию Thread.interrupted() а к остальным потокам этот вызов не будет иметь отношения? Просто метод то статический хотя тут написано: the current thread has been interrupted

Comment: @Павел да, это видно в исходном коде (там прямое обращение к `Thread.currentThread()`). А почему вас так напрягает статичность метода и выполнение на текущем треде?

Answer (score 4):

Метод `interrupted` является статическим и проверяет был ли установлен флаг прерывания у текущего потока. При этом флаг прерывания после вызова этого метода **сбрасывается**.

Метод `isInterrupted()` позволяет проверить флаг прерывания у потока, для которого этот метод был вызван. При этом сам флаг не сбрасывается.

> И в каком потоке флаг будет проверятся, если мы применяем
>   Thread.interrupted(), имея в виду что к объекту статические методы не
>   привязаны?

Будет проверен флаг прерывания у текущего потока, в котором и происходит эта проверка.